# Providing classes with their own data

Tags: c++, class, pointers

It's very easy to give a class access to `argc`, `argv`, and `environ`. The variable `char **environ` is globally available and `argc` and `argv` can simply be passed as arguments to class objects' constructors.

But what if the object needs to modify the information to which the elements of `argv` and `environ` point? In those situations objects commonly create copies of the information stored in global data or that they receive via arguments.

I want to concentrate on that part: make copies of available data. My starting point is the following outline of the class `CopyCat`:

```
    #ifndef INCLUDED_COPYCAT_
    #define INCLUDED_COPYCAT_

    class CopyCat
    {
        size_t d_size;
        char **d_data;

        public:
            CopyCat();                          // copies environ
            CopyCat(int argc, char **argv);
            CopyCat(char **data);               // cp. any environ-like variable

        private:
    };

    #endif
```

Once the constructors return its data members should contain *deep copies* (not only they should point to their own arrays of pointers, but each element of those arrays must point to copies of the corresponding elements of their source-arrays) of the received data.

I want to have the implementation of the class's header and internal header files and the implementations of the class's constructors. Any ideas?

Comment: ***But what if the object needs to modify the information to which the elements of argv and environ point?*** Make a copy. Probably use `std::vector<std::string>` to hold the arguments instead of argc, and argv

Comment: The variables passed to the program belong to the OS.  There is no guarantee that you can write to them.